# Why is this printing 5 5 5 instead of 5 6 7? (multiple singleton calls)

Tags: python, singleton

I'm trying to create a asingleton class that adds 1 to 'a' every time the class is called:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    a=0
    def __new__(self):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Singleton,self).__new__(self)
        self.a+=1
        return self._instance

x=Singleton()
x.a=5
print (x.a)
y=Singleton()
print (y.a)
z=Singleton()
print (z.a)
```

Comment: Singletons like this are not worth the effort: they are difficult to test, and mislead the caller.  Why not create a factory function if that is what you want?  Defining a "class" that actually doesn't make new instances is silly.  It's a Java idiom that has no place in Python.

Comment: @NedBatchelder It's not "a Java idiom". It is a design pattern, once popular, but proven to be mostly useless. It was known long before Java was introduced.

Comment: @BartoszKP Java has popularized it, and the crowds of people who believe that "Object Oriented" means, "the way Java works" continue to over-apply these patterns beyond their reasonable use.  As long as we agree that it is mostly useless, we don't have to agree on the pedigree... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    a=0
    def __new__(self):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Singleton,self).__new__(self)
        self._instance.a+=1
        return self._instance
```

Comment: This is not an elegant solution. It sure works in this particular case, but the common idiom is to keep *class* attributes (a.k.a. static attributes) at an appropriate level (i.e. as class/static attributes), not in an instance that just accidentally in this case will be the only one in existence.

Answer (score 9):

Your line:

```
x.a=5
```

assigns a *new* attribute to the *instance*, masking the class attribute. Without that assignment, the instance has no attribute `a` and the class attribute `Singleton.a` is found instead.

Meanwhile, your `__new__` function continues to alter the `Singleton.a` class attribute, but it is no longer consulted when you access the `a` instance attribute instead.

Your code would work if you altered the class attribute instead:

```
Singleton.a = 5
```

or you gave your `Singleton` class a property that delegated access to `a` to the class attribute:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    a = 0
    def __new__(self):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Singleton,self).__new__(self)
        self.a += 1
        return self._instance
    @property
    def a(self):
        return Singleton.a
    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        Singleton.a = value
```

or you set the attribute on the instance instead of the class:

```
class Singleton(object):
    _instance = None
    a = 0
    def __new__(self):
        if not self._instance:
            self._instance = super(Singleton,self).__new__(self)
        self._instance.a += 1
        return self._instance
```

as it is a singleton anyway.